# put value of different keys to a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "name": "product1",
    "Jan": 3,
    "Feb": 2,
    "Mar": 0,
    "Apr": 1,
    "May": 3,
    "Jun": 0,
    "Jul": 0,
    "Aug": 0,
    "Sep": 5,
    "Oct": 0,
    "Nov": 0,
    "Dec": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "product2",
    "Jan": 4,
    "Feb": 0,
    "Mar": 0,
    "Apr": 1,
    "May": 1,
    "Jun": 0,
    "Jul": 0,
    "Aug": 0,
    "Sep": 5,
    "Oct": 0,
    "Nov": 0,
    "Dec": 0
  }
]
```

I would like to pass the value of all the months to a single array respecting the order of the months as follows:

```
[
  {
    "name": "product1",
    "data": [3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
  },
  {
    "name": "product2",
    "data": [4, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
  }
]
```

so how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `map` it and inside that take the `name` out and get `Object.values()` of the `rest` of values:

```js
var array = [ { "name": "product1", "Jan": 3, "Feb": 2, "Mar": 0, "Apr": 1, "May": 3, "Jun": 0, "Jul": 0, "Aug": 0, "Sep": 5, "Oct": 0, "Nov": 0, "Dec": 0 }, { "name": "product2", "Jan": 4, "Feb": 0, "Mar": 0, "Apr": 1, "May": 1, "Jun": 0, "Jul": 0, "Aug": 0, "Sep": 5, "Oct": 0, "Nov": 0, "Dec": 0 }]

var result = array.map(({name,...rest})=>({ name, data : Object.values(rest)}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `map` to iterate over array of objects. Separate `name` from rest of the entries and return an object with `name` and the rest(using `Object.values()`).

```js
var arr = [ { name: "product1", Jan: 3, Feb: 2, Mar: 0, Apr: 1, May: 3, Jun: 0, Jul: 0, Aug: 0, Sep: 5, Oct: 0, Nov: 0, Dec: 0 }, { name: "product2", Jan: 4, Feb: 0, Mar: 0, Apr: 1, May: 1, Jun: 0, Jul: 0, Aug: 0, Sep: 5, Oct: 0, Nov: 0, Dec: 0 } ];
var result = arr.map(item => {
  let { name, ...rest } = item;
  return { name, data: Object.values(rest) };
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [{
    "name": "product1",
    "Jan": 3,
    "Feb": 2,
    "Mar": 0,
    "Apr": 1,
    "May": 3,
    "Jun": 0,
    "Jul": 0,
    "Aug": 0,
    "Sep": 5,
    "Oct": 0,
    "Nov": 0,
    "Dec": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "product2",
    "Jan": 4,
    "Feb": 0,
    "Mar": 0,
    "Apr": 1,
    "May": 1,
    "Jun": 0,
    "Jul": 0,
    "Aug": 0,
    "Sep": 5,
    "Oct": 0,
    "Nov": 0,
    "Dec": 0
  }
];

function GetData(data) {
  let res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    res[i] = {};
    res[i].name = data[i].name;
    res[i].data = [];
    for (let item in data[i]) {
      if (item != "name") {
        res[i].data.push(data[i][item]);
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(GetData(data));
```